# NameError: name is not defined Global Declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x

## !/bin/python3

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys


# Complete the plusMinus function below.
def plusMinus(arr):
    for i in range(0,n):
        if arr[i] > 0:
            global contorPozitiv
            contorPozitiv += 1
        elif arr[i] == 0:
            global contorZero
            contorZero += 1
        else:
            global contorNegativ 
            contorNegativ += 1
            
    print (contorPozitiv / n)
    print (contorNegativ / n)
    print (contorZero / n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    plusMinus(arr)
```

I get this error:

```
Compiler Message
Runtime Error
Error (stderr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 31, in <module>
    plusMinus(arr)
  File "Solution.py", line 20, in plusMinus
    contorNegativ += 1
NameError: name 'contorNegativ' is not defined
```

If I declare the variables before the for and initialize them , it works fine.

why doesn't it work with the global declaration inside the function?

Comment: You must define a variable for it be be used, in any scope. In your function, what do you imagine to be the value of `contorPozitiv += 1` which is equivalent to `contorPozitiv = contorPozitiv  + 1` ?

Comment: contorPozitiv = 0

Comment: Why do you believe that? Nowhere did you assign a value of `0` to `contorPozitiv` Really, ask yourself this, it should be illuminating.

Comment: Always define variables before using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `contorPositiv`. I believe that the calls to global might be a red herring here. Imagine that those variables are global, then you call `contorPozitiv += 1` which is equivalent to `contorPozitiv = contorPozitiv + 1`. The program has no idea what the value of `contorPozitiv` is, so it crashes.

Initializing the value with a simple `contorPozitiv = 0` after all the imports would likely resolve this. Same thing with all the other variables.

Answer (score 1):

> A variable has to be defined for it to be used.

Add this above your for loop.

```
contorPozitiv = 0
contorNegativ = 0
contorZero = 0
```